# Nested Pagination

Tags: pagination

Is this possible for wordpress?

Something like,

> [A] [B] [C]...[X] [Y] [**Z**]
>
> ......
>
> posts with title starting 'z'
>
> .......
>
> **1** 2 3 4 next>>

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to achieve this type of pagination?

It's an A-Z pagination which uses the post title as the basis. And for example page `Z` has entries greater than 10, make a pagination too.

Comment: coincidentally I am looking for the same thing :) Mine is within a custom taxonomy, but the principle should be the same...

Comment: Yeah @Piet.. I also need that... I just can't solve it...

Answer (score 1):

How about this, works fantastic for me!
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-z-index-list-of-post-titles-in-taxonomyphp-for-a-custom-taxonomy-term

Full credits go to [Gooitzen van der Ent](http://wordpress.org/support/profile/design_dolphin)